# Actualizar registro comparando columnas diferentes

Tags: mysql, sql

Lo que estoy intentado es generar una sentencia SQL que me encuentre los filas que tengan datos repetidos, y a la vez en diferentes columnas.

Mi tabla es algo asi:

```
ID  FECHA       UNO  DOS  TRES ESTADO
-- ----------   ---  ---  ---  -----
1  2018-02-18   21   22   23   B
2  2018-02-18   01   21   44   B
3  2018-02-18   55   66   77   B
```

Lo que tengo que hacer primero es encontrara los registros que tiene la misma fecha… eso no tengo problema.

El problema es cuando intento comparar las columnas UNO DOS y TRES a ver si tiene un valor en común.

Es lógico que voy a tener que ir comparando de UNO a DOS, UNO a TRES y de DOS a TRES.

En el ejemplo la fila 1 y 2 tiene la misma fecha y la Columna UNO tiene el Mismo Valor que DOS y por lo tanto tendría que actualizar su estado a E (error)…

```
'UPDATE `table` SET `estado` = "E" WHERE `fecha` = `fecha`'
```

Gracias...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si no entendí mal tu pregunta la solución seria la siguiente, primero prueba con SELECT a ver si te muestra los datos repetidos que deseas:

```
SELECT t.* FROM tabla AS t WHERE fecha = '2018-02-18' AND
EXISTS(SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM tabla) AS t1 WHERE t1.`fecha` = '2018-02-18' AND t.UNO = t1.DOS OR t.UNO = t1.TRES) OR
EXISTS(SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM tabla) AS t2 WHERE t2.`fecha` = '2018-02-18' AND t.DOS = t2.UNO OR t.DOS = t2.TRES) OR
EXISTS(SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM tabla) AS t3 WHERE t3.`fecha` = '2018-02-18' AND t.TRES = t3.UNO OR t.TRES = t3.DOS)
```

Luego si es correcto con UPDATE sería algo como esto

```
UPDATE tabla AS t SET estado = "E" WHERE fecha = '2018-02-18' AND
EXISTS(SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM tabla) AS t1 WHERE t1.`fecha` = '2018-02-18' AND t.UNO = t1.DOS OR t.UNO = t1.TRES) OR
EXISTS(SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM tabla) AS t2 WHERE t2.`fecha` = '2018-02-18' AND t.DOS = t2.UNO OR t.DOS = t2.TRES) OR
EXISTS(SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM tabla) AS t3 WHERE t3.`fecha` = '2018-02-18' AND t.TRES = t3.UNO OR t.TRES = t3.DOS)
```

Una pequeña explicación de lo que hace con UPDATE:
La primer fila, es decir:

```
UPDATE tabla AS t SET estado = "E" WHERE fecha = '2018-02-18' AND
```

Esta diciendo que se actualizará el estado a "E" donde la fecha sea la que buscamos, siempre y cuando cumpla con el resto del codigo, por eso
la segunda linea:

```
EXISTS(SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM tabla) AS t1 WHERE t1.`fecha` = '2018-02-18' AND t.UNO = t1.DOS OR t.UNO = t1.TRES) OR
```

Nos busca si un dato de la columna UNO se repite con la un dato de la DOS o TRES y asi las siguientes dos lineas de código:

```
EXISTS(SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM tabla) AS t2 WHERE t2.`fecha` = '2018-02-18' AND t.DOS = t2.UNO OR t.DOS = t2.TRES) OR
EXISTS(SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM tabla) AS t3 WHERE t3.`fecha` = '2018-02-18' AND t.TRES = t3.UNO OR t.TRES = t3.DOS)
```

Buscan si DOS o TRES se repiten en alguna columna. Se utiliza el comparador OR ya que en cualquiera de los tres casos se cambiará el estado a "E"

Comment: Muchas Gracias Funciono a la perfección

Comment: De nada. Me alegra que te resulte util jeje.